# Calculating the expected number of winners in a lottery

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

The odds of purchasing a winning lottery ticket are 0.23% and 1000 lottery tickets are sold. There can be multiple winners in this lottery game and the odds of one ticket winning does not impact the odds of another ticket winning.

For the above scenario, is the total number of expected winners of this lottery game simply:

```
(1000 tickets) * (0.23% chance of winning) = 2.3 expected winners
```

I think it's that simple but I have a habit of over thinking things and I can't find a straightforward example like the one described above.

Comment: What you say is correct, by linearity of expectation.  Is that what your question is?  I don't understand what you mean about an example.

Comment: @saulspatz google wasn't very helpful in providing an "explain it like I'm 5" example. So thanks for setting me straight.